# Inserting a character into a TEdit as the user is typing

Tags: delphi

I would like to add a separator character at a specified position in an TEdit as the user is typing.

For example, when a user types a four digit credit card expiration date, I would like to add a slash between the second and third digits. As they type '0610', it should appear as '06/10' for that aesthetically pleasing MM/YY look.

I would expect this to work:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (Edit1.Text.Length = 2) then Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + '/';
end;
```

But that outputs '0610/' instead of '06/10' because the pointer stays behind the slash. How can I change this?

Comment: Have you considered using of [TMaskEdit](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit) instead of regilar `TEdit`? The purpose of `TMaskEdit` is entering text in predetermined standardized format.

Comment: @SilverWarior note that the OP is using the [`TEdit.OnChangeTracking`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Edit.TEdit.OnChangeTracking) event, which is an FMX event, but `TMaskEdit` is a VCL control that is not available in FMX.

Comment: @Shiffles Why not simply use separate `TEdit` controls for the month and year? When the user enters 2 digits into the month, change focus to the year.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Brunberg correctly identified that the code belongs in the OnTyping event handler instead of OnChangeTracking. A follow-up bug I had is that users couldn't backspace past the '/' to correct an error (because every time they deleted the '/', a new one was automatically inserted). Here is the complete code I used to fix that bug and get the full desired effect:

WriteExpiry is a TEdit.

```
procedure TForm1.WriteExpiryTyping(Sender: TObject);
begin

//INSERTS A '/' AFTER THE FIRST TWO DIGITS OF THE EXPIRY DATE
 if (WriteExpiry.Text.Length = 2) then
 begin
 WriteExpiry.Text := WriteExpiry.Text + '/';
 WriteExpiry.CaretPosition := WriteExpiry.Text.Length;
 end;

//PROTECTS AGAINST USER TYPING '/' THEMSELVES AND CREATING '//'
 if (WriteExpiry.Text.Length = 4)then
 begin
 if WriteExpiry.Text[4] = '/' then
  begin
  WriteExpiry.Text := WriteExpiry.Text[1] + WriteExpiry.Text[2] + WriteExpiry.Text[3];
  WriteExpiry.CaretPosition := WriteExpiry.Text.Length;
   end;
 end;

procedure TForm1.WriteExpiryKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
//ALLOWS THE USER TO BACKSPACE PAST THE INSERTED '/'
if (Key = vkBack) and (WriteExpiry.Text.Length = 3) then
  begin
  WriteExpiry.Text := WriteExpiry.Text[1] + WriteExpiry.Text[2];
  WriteExpiry.CaretPosition := WriteExpiry.Text.Length;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: When removing a character, you don't need to concatenate the remaining individual characters back together. You should use `System.Copy()` or `TStringHelper.Substring()` or `TStringHelper.Remove()` to simplify that logic. For example, `WriteExpiry.Text[1] + WriteExpiry.Text[2] + WriteExpiry.Text[3]` should be either `Copy(WriteExpiry.Text, 1, 3)` or `WriteExpiry.Text.Substring(0, 3)` or `WriteExpiry.Text.Remove(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have added the `'/'` character, the `TEdit.CaretPosition` property is still at its current position, which is on the left side of the character.  Update the `CaretPosition` to move the caret to the right side of the character instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Edit1.Text.Length = 2) then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + '/';
    Edit1.CaretPosition := Edit1.Text.Length;
    // or: Edit1.GoToTextEnd();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This does not work. The output is still '0610/'.

Comment: Indeed, something in the FMX logic messes this up. The caret position gets set to the wrong (for our purposes) position in TStyledEdit.InsertText. I can't figure out exactly what's happening, but the solution does not work, even though it logically should.

Comment: Modifying `Edit1.Text` in `OnChangeTracking` causes a recursive call, that I guess cancels the modification. Adding the `/` in event `OnTyping` instead, seems to work as needed.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I checked TEdit's source and it shouldn't cancel the modification since the new text is already applied before the event is fired. Changing the text will fire the event again, but since the new length is not 2 then the event should not recurse further. I didn't check TStyledEdit's source to see if it interfers with this logic, though

Comment: Remy is right that it's not the recursion that is the problem. However, there is a real problem, too. I stepped through the source code. TEdit's own source code does, indeed, change the Text "early enough", but then, later, a posted message gets handled and ends up in TStyledEdit.InsertText, where things don't seem updated. It's hard to follow and I didn't manage on a short attempt, but there is something more going on here.